# Pre-selected drop down list value from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Though I have researched, I couldn't find any solution for this. I need to get the database value ("Default") as the pre-selected value of the drop down list.

```
<select name="listCustomer" id="listCustomer">
    <?php 
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT customer_name FROM customers");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value=\"" .   $row['customer_name'] . "\">" . $row['customer_name'] . "</option>";}
    ?>
</select>
```

Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a variable before the echo, something like:

```
$selected = ((strtolower($row['customer_name']) == 'default') ? 'selected' : '');
```

then change the echo to this:

```
echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['customer_name'].'">'.$row['customer_name'].'</option>';
```

Comment: Thanks friend, there are some unnecessary `"` marks in your code. Other than it, this solved my problem. But the problem now is the selected value is not going to the database now, always "Default" is inserting in to the database.

Comment: Edited code of yours:


`$sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT customer_name FROM customers");
                                       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $selected = ((strtolower($row['customer_name']) == 'default') ? 'selected' : '');
                                       echo '<option '.$selected.' value='.$row['customer_name'].'>'.$row['customer_name'].'</option>';}`

Comment: That's wrong. The double quotes in my example is NOT superfluous. All attribute-content should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Ah, sorry, there is ONE stray double quote,  I can see it now. The last double quote right before the `</option>`- I have updated the answer, try the new line of code.

Comment: Thanks dude. It works, my problem now is always pre-selected "Default" value is going to the database. What I want is inserting default value in to the database, if not other option is selected by the user, otherwise the user selecting value must go to the database.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using an if statement on the customer_name

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT customer_name FROM customers");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     if($row["customer_name"] === "Default"){
      echo "<option value=\"" .   $row['customer_name'] . "\" selected>" . $row['customer_name'] . "</option>";
     } else {
       echo "<option value=\"" .   $row['customer_name'] . "\">" . $row['customer_name'] . "</option>";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Note the selected tag on the first echo.

Comment: Thanks friend, you missed "=" mark after `$row` in `while` loop. Other than it, this solved my problem. But the problem now is the selected value is not going to the database now, always "Default" is inserting in to the database.

Comment: Thats because you insert "Default" as the value of that selected option.

Comment: Yes, but how can I insert the selecting value to the database, disregarding the default value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT customer_name FROM customers";
$result = @mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name=customer_name value=' '>";
while($drop=@mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value=$drop[customer_name]>$drop[customer_name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: if you select any value then this definitely insert into your table